# Insert Adjusted ASP Variable Cleaned with Regex into meta content="" field

Tags: html, asp.net, regex

I have an asp variable `[@@Price]` that displays with extra content - $12.69/CS
I'm having problems inserting the cleaned `[@@Price]` variable into meta field -specifically `content=""`.

I have the refex working. I use it on some google import functions

```
=REGEXEXTRACT("//*[@id='Price']/a"),"\d+\.\d{1,2}")
```

This will do as I need taking $12.69/CS and show only 12.69

What I can't seem to do is include this correctly in the HTML I need and am looking for direction and best way.

The goal is

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="12.69" />
```

Attempted already was trying to insert simple`<javascript></javascript>` inside the `content=""`
Embedding JS

```
<meta itemprop="price3" class="pricecleaned" content="javascript:regexreplace([@@Price]:\d+\.\d{1,2}, "")" />
```

Also attempted was setting dom elements in javascript with no success. Everything I attempt seems terribly inefficient and like I'm missing the obvious.

Note: The page is complicated with many variables, JavaScript, a document ready set of JavaScript

Unfortunately I can not share the internal page or link.

The goal again is 
`[@@Price]` renders in html as $12.69/CS ( this could be all sorts of /TR, /RI etc)

Results needed is the regex cleaned variable in the `content=""`
Precisely -

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="12.69" />
```

The Regex Works, I just need help how to put into the CONTENT="" so I get the end result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/JFQSxF/1/) might help you to divide your prices into two groups where using `$1` you can simply replace undesired `$` and any other non-numeric chars afterwards:

```
^\$([0-9\.\,]+).+$
```

[image]

If you wish to replace your string, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/494046/6553328) explains that how a string can be replaced using RegEx.

Comment: Thank you - As I mentioned the Regex I have works - \d+\.\d{1,2} - does the same thing and has been proven. What I can't seem to figure out is the statement to insert that regex into the meta content="" spot.
content="javascript:regextract([@@Price]:\d+\.\d{1,2}" etc. < This line - and how to put the variable, the regex INTO the content="" quotes.